# Hunt the Wumpus - Room Connection

Tags: c++

So I'm writing a version of the game [Hunt the Wumpus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunt_the_Wumpus) in C++. The only real difference is that I'm not worried about the cave having a dodecahedron shape.

So far I've implemented the creation of the cave and the random insertion of the hero, bat, wumpus, and pit.

```
// Hunt the Wumpus

#include "std_lib_facilities.h"
#include "time.h"

class Room{
    bool is_occupied;
    bool has_wumpus;
    bool has_bat;
    bool has_pit;

public:
    Room()  // default constructor
    {
        is_occupied = false;
        has_wumpus = false;
        has_bat = false;
        has_pit = false;
    }

    void random_insert(vector<Room>& v);
};

void Room::random_insert(vector<Room>& v)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int random_room = 0;
    bool crowded = true;

    random_room = rand() % 20;  // insert hero
    v[random_room].is_occupied = true;

    while(crowded)  // insert...THE WUMPUS!
    {
        random_room = rand() % 20;
        if(v[random_room].is_occupied) ;
        else if(!v[random_room].is_occupied)
        {
             v[random_room].has_wumpus = true;
             crowded = false;
        }
    }

    crowded = true;
    while(crowded)  // insert bat
    {
        random_room = rand() % 20;
        if(v[random_room].is_occupied || v[random_room].has_wumpus) ;
        else if(!v[random_room].is_occupied && !v[random_room].has_wumpus)
        {
             v[random_room].has_bat = true;
             crowded = false;
        }
    }

    crowded = true;
    while(crowded)  // insert pit
    {
        random_room = rand() % 20;
        if(v[random_room].is_occupied || v[random_room].has_wumpus || v[random_room].has_bat) ;
        else if(!v[random_room].is_occupied && !v[random_room].has_wumpus && !v[random_room].has_bat)
        {
             v[random_room].has_pit = true;
             crowded = false;
        }
    }
}

vector<Room> create(Room& r)
{
    vector<Room> c;
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
        c.push_back(r);
    return c;
}

int main()
{
    Room r;
    vector<Room> cave = create(r);   // create cave
    r.random_insert(cave);    // randomly insert things

}
```

I've got a good idea of how I'm going to implement everything else with bats dropping the hero into random places, shooting, outputting current situation, etc.

However, I'm not sure how to deal with randomly connecting the rooms in the cave. I've considered doing some kind of random sort in the vector and then connecting the rooms to the left and right with pointers, but that is just a long hallway, not a cave. Maybe I could create some kind of coordinates system? Does anyone have any recommendations? Thanks.

Comment: Irrelevant to the question, but using initializer lists for constructors is faster and safer.

Comment: I'm not really concerned about speed. I already finished it, but I'll change it anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution is to pick a room with less than 3 exits, and connect to it to a random room (watch out for double connections of course). Once there are no rooms with less than 3 exits, terminate. With only 20 or so rooms it doesn't really matter how slow your implementation is.

Edit: There's a chance that some part of the map will be "cut off" from the rest this way, or connected only by one corridor. It may help to start off with a "long hallway" and *then* apply the above algorithm, to be sure this can't occur.

Comment: If you make it so each room ends up with exactly 3 exits using this approach, the dodecahedral shape will be a side-effect.

Comment: But how should I handle the actual connections? Pointers? Or should I give class Room data members for exits 1, 2, and 3 and then assign those?

Comment: Right now I'm toying with having the exit data members be of type int and assigning in that way. When specific data on the exits is needed I just ask for cave[exit]

Comment: You can use an index into your list of rooms, or cross-pointers between rooms.

Use a vector for room exits if you want to allow a variable number of exits... randomly generating a map where each room has EXACTLY 3 exits is a tiny bit trickier.

@Justin: No, there are other ways of making each room have exactly 3 exits than forming a dodecahedron.

Comment: I'm flagging this as the answer because I have a good idea of where I'm going now, thanks. The only thing I don't like is that(at least the way I'm implementing it), I need to make sure that a room isn't used more than 3 times for an exit, so I need to set a counter for each of the numbers 0-19 which is really ugly.

Comment: At least until I think of something more clever.

Comment: Yes, there is a danger of cutting off a part of the map.  Unlikely but possible--when you're done generating test it for validity, if it fails redraw.  As for making sure it's not used more than 3 times--all connections are bidirectional, you can see how many are left.  Check before making the connection.  To speed things up keep a list of rooms that aren't full, don't even consider full ones.  Watch out for the case of having only one room left--if that happens, redraw.

Comment: @trikker Exits should be reciprocal right? If A has an exit to B then B should have an exit to A. If that's the case then testing if a room is used as an exit 3 times should be identical to testing if a room has 3 exits.

Answer (score 0):

You can do some pretty complicated algorithms for this. I made a [random maze generator](http://www.otcsw.com/maze.php) in Java that uses the Drunkard's Walk algorithm to accomplish this. Effectively, you iterate through every single grid location once, then as you create a room at that location you begin placing rooms at a random available adjacent location, and connect the two if they aren't already. Keep going until you can't make a new room adjacent to the previous location, then iterate to the next available grid space. This is a little bit complicated, but works well. The best way to understand it is to run that maze generator I linked you to, and watch the maze generation in action. You should understand it quickly.

Another solution is just to store every room in a 2D grid, corresponding to their actual locations. Then simply iterate through each grid space and randomly assign pointers to the adjacent rooms. Some will have 4 connections, some 3, 2, or 1 (have a minimum of 1). I would give each room a Room *north, Room *east, Room *south, Room *west variable group, and if any of them are nil that means there's a wall there.